# preventDefault dont stop submit process

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

How can I make that preventDefault work, I don't understand the syntax well, if you can help me thank you very much

The Alerts work but the preventDefault does not stop the process, it just happens as knowing that there is an alias but it does not stop the submission of the form

```
$('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "validar_rut_alias.php",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (id, nombre) {
            if (nombre.alias == $("#alias").val()) {
                alert("alias registered ");
                e.preventDefault();
            } else if (nombre.rut == $("#rut").val()) {
                alert("rut registered");
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to call it before the ajax call, not after it has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that the preventDefault is the first call in your click event, as follows:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "validar_rut_alias.php",
        dataType: "json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (id, nombre) {
            if (nombre.alias == $("#alias").val()) {
                alert("alias registered ");
            } else if (nombre.rut == $("#rut").val()) {
                alert("rut registered");
            }
        });
    });
});
```